# Xlib : Segmentation fault on multithreading

Tags: c++, animation, segmentation-fault, pthreads, xlib

My attempt is to write an Xlib wrapper for the purpose of implementing triple buffering methods. Using which a person needs only compute their display matrix and forward it to the API for displaying. I have two separate threads for handling events and display. The events thread seems to execute without any issue, however, the display thread, when used with standard Xlib functions such as XDrawRectangle, XFillArc, XSetForeground, etc. seems to cause a segmentation fault of an unknown nature.

This is my thread execution part :

```
int startx(){
    pthread_t eventsThread, displayThread;
    char msg1[15] ="Events Thread", msg2[15] = "Display Thread";
    int pid1, pid2;
    pid1 = pthread_create( &eventsThread, NULL, eventsHandler, (void*) msg1);
    pid2 = pthread_create( &displayThread, NULL, displayHandler, (void*) msg2);
    pthread_join(eventsThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(displayThread, NULL); 
    return 0;
};
```

This is my displayHandler :

```
void *displayHandler(void* args){
    cout<<connectionNumber<<endl;
    Color c(50,50,250);
    int width = 40, height = 60,x = 500, y = 100;
    for(int i=0;i<1300;i++){
        XSetForeground(display, xgraphics, c.decimal);
        XDrawRectangle(display, mainWindow, xgraphics, x, y, width, height);
        XFlush(display);
    }
}
```

The eventsThread seems to be executing without error. Also, I have tried making the display function a part of the main program, with the same results.

If somebody could tell me an alternative/correct method to paint the window using matrices, it would be most appreciated.

Note : Color is a self made class for ease of colour computation.

Comment: `void *displayHandler(void* args)` should probably `return NULL;` but I don't know if the missing return is causing the problem. Also: Do you have C++11 (or later)? If so, take a look at the standard `<thread>` library.

Comment: Do you call `XInitThreads` before using threads? This function initializes Xlib support for concurrent threads and must be the first Xlib function a multi-threaded program calls.

Comment: @Siliace Calling XInitThreads before the threads creation or execution had no affect.

Comment: Are the global variables you use in the handler used in more than one thread? If so, are the X-functions thread safe?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am making use of global variables (such as some display specifications as int, some Window Display and GC) across both the event thread and the display thread. Whether it is thread safe, is something I need to know as well. I do not think that I would be facing such problems, if it were.

Comment: @SupratikChatterjee One way to make sure that the shared resources aren't accessed at the same time in more than one of your threads would be to start the event handlers  by acquiring a mutex, that you then release when leaving the handler. Btw, why do the drawing 1300 times in the handler?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Single execution works sometimes. So, I had to check for multiple executions. I'll try writing a mutex for them. As you point out, the display might be open for a read in the events thread, while attempting a write from the display thread. If so, then that might just be the solution to my problem.

Comment: Great! ... and do you really need to use bare C `pthreads`? You'll get what you need from the C++ `<thread>` library with nice context handled locks etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Writing a mutex solved the problem. Thank you for pointing out that elementary mistake. It works properly now. Removes the need for using a thread library as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crashes for me before the `howdy` line. Uncommenting the `return NULL;` line makes it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *displayHandler(void* args) {
    char* txt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(args);
    std::cout << txt << "\n";
    // return NULL;
}

int startx(){
    pthread_t displayThread;
    char msg2[15] = "Display Thread";
    int pid2;
    pid2 = pthread_create( &displayThread, NULL, displayHandler, (void*) msg2);
    pthread_join(displayThread, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    startx();
    std::cout << "howdy\n";
}
```

Comment: Standard functions work well. It's the XLib functions that don't.

Comment: @SupratikChatterjee Ok. So, adding `return NULL;` didn't have any effect?

Comment: Absolutely none. Made no difference.

Comment: @SupratikChatterjee Ok, but keep it there anyway. It's UB if you don't.

Comment: Okay, will do the same for my events thread as well in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted Lyngmo points out. The problem lay with the fact that Xlib has no thread safety implemented for writing to the display. So writing a mutex presented a solution.

If any of the event masks are set to write to the screen, separate threads for both become pointless. Instead making the masks toggle variables, allow them to work simultaneously.